VSCode test runner gets stuck while debugging Playwright tests when closing the browser
When I am debugging and I close the browser, it doesn't work anymore. I click on the "Cancel test run" button and the tests are not running anymore, but the test explorer is loading forever as shown in the image. I have to be restarting vscode all the time and this is annoying.
stuck screen
This wasn't happening last week and it is only happening after last updates. Could be related to any of the following configuration?

.vscode/setting.json

{
    "playwright.workspaceSettings": {
        "configs": [
            {
                "relativeConfigFile": "playwright.config.ts",
                "selected": true,
                "enabled": true,
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "name": "chromium",
                        "enabled": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}


setting.json file from vscode Manage > Settings

{
    "nxConsole.showNodeVersionOnStartup": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": "steps/*.ts",
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*.feature",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "step-definition-generator.runner": "playwright",
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "playwright.reuseBrowser": true,
    "playwright.showTrace": false,
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
}

Thanks in advance.
I've tried changing the debug configuration from Manage>Settings but did't work:
Manage>Settings
